# incorrect id added to link_to when using form_for in a block

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When an admin signs into my application they land on a page showing all Users with id, email, etc. but also have the ability to change a user's role.

When I try to change the role by selecting a new role in the dropdown and hitting submit, the correct `users_path` is followed but instead of `id` being passed to params, it is pushing another attribute, `api_key`, from the user model.

I know I could alter this code to push `(id: user.id)` as I've done in a few of the instances below but I'd really like to understand how this is happening as this wasn't a problem before and I really can't understand how/why its grabbing `api_key`.

`users_controller`

```
def index
  unless current_user.application_admin?
    redirect_to :back, :alert => "You do not have permission to access this page."
  end
  @users = User.all
end
```

The view/form in question, `index.html.erb`

```
<table class="table">
        <tbody>
          <% @users.map do |user| %>
            <tr>
              <td><%= user.id %></td>
              <td><%= link_to user.name, user_path(id: user.id) %></td>
              <td><%= user.email %></td>
              <td><%= user.created_at %></td>
              <td><%= link_to user.email, user_path(id: user.id) %></td>
              <td>
                <%= form_for user do |f| %>
                  <%= f.select(:role, User.roles.keys.map {|role| [role.titleize,role]}) %>
                  <%= f.submit 'Change Role', :class => 'button-xs' %>
                <% end %>
              </td>
              <td>
                <%= link_to("Delete user", user_path(id: user.id), :data => { :confirm => "Are you sure?" }, :method => :delete, :class => 'button-xs') unless user == current_user %>
              </td>
            </tr>
          <% end %>
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

Edit to specify:

Everywhere I've added the `user_path(id: user.id)` is working properly.  What I'm most curious about is how, in that embedded `form_for` inside the table, does the submit button inserting a model attribute (`api_key`) other than `id`.

Comment: try to use "user_path(user)" instead of user_path(user.id)

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  Everywhere you see that user_path(id: user.id) is working properly.  That line in the delete user was a typo.  Added an edit to specify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `form_for user do |f|` should evaluate to:

```
form_for user, as: :user, url: user_path(user), method: :patch, html: { class: "edit_user", id: "edit_user_45" } do |f|
```

`user_path(user)` will run `User#to_param` to retrieve the identifier. By default it returns `id` so either you or one of your gems overwrote it to return `api_key`.

Quick test you can run in rails console:

```
> user = User.last
> app.user_path(user)
=> "/users/45"
> def user.to_param
*   "a"
* end  
=> :to_param
> app.user_path(user)
=> "/users/a"
```

Reference:
[form_for](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/form_for)
[to_param](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/to_param)

Comment: Thank you!  While I haven't figured out how it was overwritten yet, your response taught me something I didn't know could happen.  Plus, I didn't know you could run the route `app.user_path(user)` like that.